# Run a function on each new 'popup' event for a Chrome extension (Manifest v3)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension using Manifest v3 and I'd like:

1. The `action` to specify a popup page (i.e. `popup.html`) and
2. Have a function run each time that popup is displayed.

I know the Chrome Extension API has the `action.onClicked` event (to which I could subscribe in `background.js`), but the documentation ([here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/)) states:

> The `action.onClicked` event will not be dispatched if the extension action has specified a popup to show on click on the current tab.

Unfortunately, I want to *both* show the popup page *and* run a quick function (to update that popup page) on each fresh extension button push. Since the popup page is itself a web page, is there some other event to which I can subscribe for when the popup is *displayed* (each time)?

Answer (score 1):

Eh, solved. It appears the `popup.html` page (and any associated `<script>`) is simply reloaded on each button push. (I'd mistakenly thought perhaps it was loaded once then *hidden* but kept in-memory.)